# How do I keep the Recovery HD and EFI partitions from automatically mounting on my MacBook Air?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro, efi, recovery-hd

I've set Finder preferences on my MacBook Air running OS X 10.9.1 to show everything on my desktop:

[image: Finder Preferences screen shot]

I've noticed that storage partitions called **Recovery HD** and **EFI** appear there:

[image: screen shot of storage partitions on my desktop]

What are they? Is there a setting I can use to hide them?

I've noticed I can eject them, but they will reappear later, such as when I wake my MacBook Air after sleeping.

**Update:** I'm using [Mountain](http://appgineers.de/mountain/) (which I recommend), and it turns out either the "Mount all unmounted volumes on wake from sleep" setting was on by default, or I didn't remember setting it.

[image]

Since I turned it off those partitions have stopped mounting automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is currently set to mount and show hidden partitions, which is unusual. To get control of this feature, you need to [activate the Debug menu in Disk Utility](http://web.archive.org/web/20160417070107/http://www.ernieflores.net/osx-page-2/view-mount-hidden-partitions-in-mac-os-x/) which then gives you the option of viewing and mounting hidden partitions, or indeed, making them hidden again.

1. In Terminal, run the command

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility DUDebugMenuEnabled 1
   ```
2. Launch (or relaunch Disk Utility)
3. In the Debug menu, uncheck Show Every Partition.

Answer (score 1):

They are hidden partitions in OS X. Showing all partitions in Disk Utility also shows the partitions in the list:

[image]

…and `diskutil list`:

```
1:         EFI EFI          209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:   Apple_HFS Mac SSD      150.0 GB   disk0s2
3:  Apple_Boot Recovery HD  650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

They are usually not mounted by default and therefore not shown on the desktop regardless of your settings in Finder.

Try resetting your NVRAM (boot with ⌘⌥PR until the *second* boot chime).

Comment: Resetting my NVRAM didn't work. The partitions mounted again after waking from sleep.